# Flask Migrate keeps trying to create existing tables

Tags: python-3.x, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I have an existing Flask app.
I am trying to integrate schema version control on an existing Oracle db.

When running:

```
python manage.py db migrate
```

Flask is trying to create tables that are already in the database. 
I tried running:

```
python manage.py db stamp head
```

I then create a test model and run migrate again; but it tries to create the same tables as before. it does not try to create the test table.

```
python manage.py history
```

> 'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and '
>   6a6b9b154ef9 -> a099c94a341c (head), empty message 31222b334ac8 ->
>   6a6b9b154ef9, empty message f267264efa75 -> 31222b334ac8, empty
>   message 8e30654a437d -> f267264efa75, empty message  ->
>   8e30654a437d, empty message

Comment: Can you add in your question the output of `python manage.py db history`?

Comment: I just added the history

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer [here](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-Migrate/issues/93#issuecomment-168540045)

Had to do with alembic not looking at tables in the SYSTEM Tablespace.

In Oracle SQL Developer right click on on the

```
right click on on the Table -> Edit -> Storage -> Tablespace
```

Change from SYSTEM to USER.

If someone can add a programming solution to this please add it.